# How do you add custom fields and website fields in the new Directory API?

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-profiles-api, google-admin-sdk

In the Profiles Data API you could add custom fields via `gContact:userDefinedField`. You can also create website links (via `gContact:website`) which would display as clickable links in the Contacts Web UI.

My question is how do you create custom fields and website fields for User resources in [the new Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensible schema isn't available yet but is coming according to the Admin SDK announcement I/O Session. See the video at:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5jgUimpFnw&t=16m35s